# Infinite loop with input() in python 3 even considering tutorial about it

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I use Python 3.7.1.

I will introduce my expectations to be clearer for the reader.
I enter a choice through the `input()` and if I wrote a `while` loop, this is in order to ask me again if I enter a wrong "command"(a wrong input).

So let's see the script.py below:

```
champ_choix=""
while champ_choix!="1" or champ_choix!="2":
    champ_choix=input("Pour cat_course tapez 1\nPour hippodrome tapez 2\n")
    print("L'input est : {}".format(champ_choix))#print the input is:
    print("le type de l'input est: {}".format(type(champ_choix)))#print the type is:

    if champ_choix=="1":
    ##CHOIX DE LA COLLECTION##
        collection_num=""
        while collection_num!="1" or collection_num!="2":
            collection_num=input("Pour la collection geny_rapp tapez 1\nPour la collection geny_cotes tapez 2\n")
        #Do some instructions useless to show

    if champ_choix=="2":
        subprocess.run(['scrapy crawl test_shell -a nom_prix=True'],shell=True)
        #if choice is "2" launch a spider with scrapy
```

I need to precise that I tried first without indented the `if` conditions above, and using other words of conditions: `if champ_choix=="1": .... elif champ_choix=="2":... else: pass` but it still does not work.

The issue is when I launch the script in the terminal it gives me:

```
(base) avy@avy-Moi:~/folder$ python script.py
Pour cat_course tapez 1
Pour hippodrome tapez 2
2 <- the input I entered
L'input est : 2
le type de l'input est: <class 'str'>
Pour cat_course tapez 1
Pour hippodrome tapez 2
```

As you can see, it really instantiate the right input: 2, and it is the right type of the input: str. But it makes an infinite loop, and don't understand why because considering [this tutorial](http://introtopython.org/while_input.html#Using-while-loops-to-make-menus) that's the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while champ_choix!="1" or champ_choix!="2"
```

doesn't work like you think it does. `champ_choix` would have to have two values at the same time for that to ever be false, and that isn't possible.

You want to make sure it isn't equal to `"1"`, **and** it isn't equal to `"2"`:

```
while champ_choix!="1" and champ_choix!="2"
```

Comment: I changed as you said, replace the `or` by `and` but I still have the infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I will accept your answer as soon as possible. I wrote a `print()` within the choice equal 2. It works, that's a matter of subprocess now because it does nothing as I expected first of all, and I did not expect it asks me again when instructions are done. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check `champ_choix` against 1 or 2 is using `in`, or in this case `not in`:

```
while champ_choix not in ('1', '2'):
```

Equally, you could use a `not` around the whole expression and negate the comparison operators (turn `!=` into `==`):

```
while not (champ_choix == '1' or champ_choix == '2'):
```